# External Content Type Column in SharePoint list (sort/filter non-integer fields)

Tags: sorting, sharepoint-2010, sqldatatypes, type-conversion, external-contenttype

I am on SharePoint 2010 and have a custom list. I have added an External Data column using the external content type which links to a view in another SQL database.

I have been able to successfully look up the field in my custom list, pull across related items and refresh them as they get updated in the other database. (For example, if my lookup value is an employee ID, then I am successfully able to bring across number of years the employee has been employed (integer value), employee name (string), hiring date (date), email (string).

The issue: When these fields come into my sharepoint list, although I can see them in the list, I CANNOT sort/filter on anything except for the integer value.

For example: I can sort/filter based on years the employee has been with the company, but I cannot sort/filter by employee name or hiring date.

I need this to be in a custom list vs. external list because there are other columns in this list which would be populated through sharepoint infopath form (for example, notes related to the employee record, last training date, etc.).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: I found a work around for the date field (still not sure what to do about the string fields). What I did is in the SQL view, I changed the format of the column to integer using a CAST statement. Then in SharePoint list, I created a calculated column that equals the integer column coming from SharePoint (the formulas only show integer columns in the available columns list) and added 2 (=[years employed_int]+2). I made the format of the calculated column to be date and that seems to have worked. Not a clean solution, but at least it is a work around that will prevent delays to my scheduled implementation.